# How best to arrange a rope that you intend to sleep on top of

Tags: ropes, sleeping, bivouac

Recently i was forced to take a long nap in a particular set of toilets at the top of a particular peak after missing the last bin down.

I had no bivvy gear, but the toilets were heated and i was able to sleep reasonably well. I sprawled out my rope on the floor and slept on top of it.

I'm interested to know if there is a particular way of doing this for maximum comfort. Ta

Comment: I imagine the type, diameter and amount of rope has a lot of impact on the question.   http://media.iwm.org.uk/ciim5/29/248/large_000000.jpg

Comment: @JamesJenkins They look happy. im just talking 60m 9.8mm dynamic half rope.

Answer (score 6):

My recommendation would be to coil it into a carpet, it's be the easiest and most comfortable, but it wouldn't stay together very well. You could put your tarp over top if you have a rope tarp, that would help keep it nicely coiled a bit, but tossing and turning at night would eventually end you up in the same position as just messily flaking your rope out.

Start in the centre and coil the rope round and round until you have a mat like so:

[image]

Make two round coils, or fold your rope at about 5ft long then coil along the length so you have a longer mat to sleep on.

Another option, which will take a lot of time to tie and untie, and no small amount of skill, is to weave a mat:

[image]

This option would take hours, but if you're stuck with nothing to do, it could help you pass the time.

Personally, I wouldn't want to sleep on my rope for fear of doing some unseen damage to it, even though it's unlikely you'd do any damage to it on a clean floor.

Maybe include in your rope log that the rope was used to catch some Zzz's.

Comment: A tightly coiled 200 ft 10mm rope would result in a 5 foot long mat that is only 0.4 m wide. I doubt that would be comfortable to sleep on. There may be a shape that works, but you might be better off making a pillow.

Comment: @strongbad You only really need to pad under your torso, but you're right that some may find it more comfortable to just use the rope as a pillow. It'd be better for your rope too.

Comment: Wouldn't weaving a mat and then un-weaving it later lead to a horribly twisted rope? That might affect the handling when the rope is used as a climbing rope again.